# PHP Not Executing Code To Create Database

Tags: sql

I wrote the following code and I'm trying to make an install to create the databases and tables for the SQL but I can't figure out why it's not creating the databases or the tables.

```
CONFIG.PHP

    <?php
    // Database Details
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';

    //Install Settings
    $root_username = 'root';
    $root_password = 'password';

    // Install Settings Advanced - Do Not Modify For Default Settings
    $database = 'Sims2';
    ?>

INSTALL.PHP
        <?php
    include 'config.php';

    // Remove any instance of .mysqli_connect_error() before publishing

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
    if (!$conn) {die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());};

    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE Sims2";
    if (!$conn){die("Error creating database: ".mysqli_connect_error());};

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE TEACHERS (
        id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        uid VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        pwd VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
        );";
    if(!$conn){die("Error creating table: ".mysqli_connect_error());};

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (
        id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        last VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        gender VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
        dob VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        semail VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        phone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        tutor VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
        );";
    if(!$conn){die("Error creating table: ".mysqli_connect_error());};

    $sql = "INSERT INTO TEACHERS (uid, pwd) VALUES ($root_username,$root_password)";
    if(!$conn){die("Error creating root account: ".mysqli_connect_error());};

    echo "Done";
    ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where do you *try* to execute any of your SQL commands?  (Hint: You don't.)  (Second hint: `mysqli_connect_error` is for connection errors, not query errors.  Take a look at `mysqli_error` for those.)  From this code, it looks like your best bet at the moment is to walk through an introductory tutorial on using `mysqli` in PHP.  This usage is... way off.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot now >.<